# Lower bound of the time complexity of heap building

Tags: ds.algorithms

A lower bound of the needed number of comparision to build a [heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29) is given by [GASTON H. GONNET and J. IAN MUNRO](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/0215068) as following

> THEOREM 4. $1.3644... n + O(lg n)$ comparisons are necessary, not only in the worst
>   case, but also on the average to create a heap on n elements.
>
> Proof - A reasonably straightforward enumeration shows that there are $H(n)=
> n !/\prod t_i$ valid heaps on a set on n numbers where $t_i$ is the size of the heap rooted at
>   node $i$. A lower bound on the average number of comparisons required to permit one
>   of $n!$ possible input sequences to one of these orders is $$\lg(n!/H(n))=\sum \lg t_i.$$

I understand how the number of valid heap is calculated. But I don't know information theory so I can't see how the last equation is the lower bound. Is there any theorem or book I can check to see how this works?

Comment: Welcome to cstheory, a Q&A site for *research-level* questions in *theoretical computer science* (TCS). Your question does not appear to be a research-level question in TCS. Please see the [FAQ] for more information on what is meant by this. Your question might be suitable for [cs.se] which has a broader scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is essentially using decision tree model to obtain the lower-bound. There are $n!/H(n)$ leafs in the decision tree, it is a binary tree, therefore the height of the tree is at least $\lg (n!/H(n))$.